# Google Map API 3 with OSM overlay

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm using GeoXml3 to parse XML files in Google Map and would like to add OSM as custom maptype. I fiddled with [this](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example) example but it hides completely the original Google layers.

I've found a couple of other examples but unfortunately all of them are using the V2 API.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample page of what you want (even it uses google v2 api)?

Comment: [A V2 more complex example](http://www.maps-for-free.com/index.html)

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0vhvZKRL) modified code from OSM wiki. It displays Google Map controls with OSM layer, but switching maptypes doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, maybe your question is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14597/add-a-openstreetmaps-road-data-layer-on-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: I've seen that post and the answer. I would like to use OSM a maptype and not just part of it (e.g road layer). I think my pastebin example is almost there...

Comment: Not sure to get you! How can you use the all OSM dataset without hidding the original google layer? Or maybe you would like to use kind of opacity property ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working [example](http://maps.caseypthomas.org/gosm.html). I based this off of your pastebin code and this [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image.html) in Google's doc.

Your code was missing the maxZoom parameter in the mapTypeOptions object; which is a required parameter. See:

[Google Doc](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#MapTypeInterface) (under MapType interface header)

[OSM Doc](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example), under 'Example - Using Google Maps API v3 setting OSM as a base map layer' header:

> Note that you need to set maxZoom in the ImageMapType for it to work as a base layer.

Here is the js code:

```
var osmMapTypeOptions = {
getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
    return "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" +
    zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
},
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 0,
    name: "OSM"
};

var osmMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(osmMapTypeOptions); 
var map;

function initialize(){

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57, 21);
var mapOpts = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: latlng,
    panControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['OSM',google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },                  
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpts);
map.mapTypes.set('OSM', osmMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('OSM');
```

Comment: Is it possible to use another OSM format besides PNG? (e.g., XML, etc)